Number missing in dtable baseline table
How can I add a row of number missing into a baseline table created with dtable in Stata 18?
Example baseline table:
clear
cls

webuse brcancer

/* Generate missing values */
set seed 1234
gen rand1 = runiform()
gen rand2 = runiform()
replace x1 = . if rand1 < 0.2
replace x2 = . if rand2 < 0.2

/* Baseline table */
dtable x1 i.x2, by(hormon) 


----------------------------------------------------------------
                                 Hormonal therapy               
                         0               1            Total     
----------------------------------------------------------------
N                     440 (64.1%)    246 (35.9%)    686 (100.0%)
Age (years)       51.256 (10.020) 57.368 (9.127) 53.436 (10.135)
Menopausal status                                               
  1                   185 (52.3%)     43 (22.6%)     228 (41.9%)
  2                   169 (47.7%)    147 (77.4%)     316 (58.1%)
----------------------------------------------------------------


For each missing, I would makea row of missing with the number.

I'd advise posting this on Statalist. The StataCorp developer most associated with this command watches posts here.
